# How to add email-opt in instant article

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I have search all over internet and asked the instant article team too in instant article facebook page, 
but I can't find the answer the way too put email-opt in instant.

I have put <form>, <button≫, <input> tag on instant article editor, it successfully saved but it's not shown in page manager apps.

I have asked to place that write article about facebook instant article, but no answer too.

I have searched at facebook instant article docs dev, but couldn't find it  too.

Is there place I'm missing?

Does it need particular step like we must have facebook leads, or audience network or something first?

I would appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked this on the FB Dev forum and they said it's still being rolled out. Only select publishers have this option for the time being.

Source: [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10103216845582465&notif_t=answers_answered&notif_id=1486581206180436)